# In RSA encryption system, public key is ($n=11 \times 13, e= 11$) and cipher-text is $C =17$, answer the following questions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In RSA encryption system, public key is ($n=11 \times 13, e= 11$) and cipher-text is $C =17$, answer the following questions.

(1) Find the private key $d$.

(2) Using the private key $d$, find the plain-number $Z_{77}$ according to the cipher-text $C$.

What I've done:

I found private key d which is $11$ using EEA.

but I don't understand how to do second question.

Could you please help me on this question?

Comment: Can you follow this example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586263/rsa-encryption-decryption-scheme?

Comment: What is $Z$ under 77?

Answer (score 0):

$n=143$ and $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = 10\cdot 12 = 120$.

We need $d = e^{-1} \bmod{120}$ and indeed this is $d=11$ as $ed= 121 = 1\bmod{120}$.

The ciphertext is $c=17$ so the plain is (by the RSA formula) equal to

$$17^{11} \bmod {143}$$

which equals $127$ ($17^2 \bmod{143} = 3$ ,$17^4 \bmod{143} = 9$, $17^8 \bmod{143} = 81$ and $17^{11} = 17^8 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 17^1$ so modulo $143$ we get $81 \cdot 3 \cdot 17 = 127 \bmod{143}$ this way we keep the numbers small..)

I don't know what $Z_{77}$ would be, or even what you mean by that?

Comment: I am not sure about Z_77. The question simply says what I wrote on the text.