# Decrypting RSA cipher text when given N e and d

Tags: cryptography

The cipher text is wqlizYbFyjOp95Bt.ViLWHhEBx2
N=7231645985673347207280720222548553948759779729581
e=3
d=4821097323782215625692549251331855329314609896043
where d is the private key
How do i solve this?

Comment: How was the ciphertext encoded as it includes both lower and upper case characters? Without knowing that, there is no way to figure it out without guessing that piece. $$\Large m \equiv c^d \pmod{N}$$

Comment: @Moo it was encoded with 64 letter alphabet abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-

Comment: You need to convert those letters, special characters (like the period) and numbers to numbers such that we can use the formula above. Does $a = 01, b = 02...$ or something else using that scheme?

Comment: @Moo In numbers it comes out as 2216118255013124940156157271962478374733730272354 a=0 b=1.... -=63

Comment: See if this comes out to anything meaningful $$\Large m \equiv c^d \pmod{N} = 970076824680893648179763130080906806851394045029$$

Comment: @Moo Nope...It's a multiple choice question and the first letters are Llan although one option is None of the above

Comment: Do they provide any other additional information on how they chunked up the message - did they do it five characters at a time or something like that? Perhaps they did it in blocks instead of a giant blob?

Comment: Nope no other info..Just what i have stated above in the question

Comment: It is hard to say, I would try various things to see.

Comment: How would i approach this if i didn't have the deciphering key?

Comment: See the process here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586263/rsa-encryption-decryption-scheme

Comment: Is the encoding like working in base-64 instead of 10, or is it some string manipulation? Examples? The problem is underspecified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ciphertext was `wqlizYbFyjOp95Bt.ViLWHhEBx2` using the 64-base
alphabet (from the comments; it should have been part of the question!) `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-`

You can write functions to convert strings to numbers and numbers back to strings, e.g. using Python:

```
def toDec(c):
    alph='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-'
    value=0
    b=1 #value of current position
    for w in reversed(list(c)):
            value += b*alph.index(w)
            b *= 64
    return value
```

and

```
def toBase(n):
    alph='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-'
    s=''
    while n:
            s =  str(alph[n % 64]) + s
            n -= n%64
            n/=64
    return s
```

So your ciphertext string represents the number `c=2032648950572077788772410497891338100431128212982` which is indeed $< N$ 
where `N= 7231645985673347207280720222548553948759779729581`

Decryption in RSA is exponentation by $d$ modulo $N$: $m=c^d \bmod{N}$ and this gives the number $m=49409962907892021177240969231692222477$.

Converting back to the base again to get a textual representation we get

`toBase(m) = Llanbedr-Pont-Steffan`

which seems to be the Welsh name for [Lampeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampeter)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! How exactly did you run the Python code?

Comment: @Pkr96 I put it in a file and called the Python interpreter on the command line. I always work on Unix systems (macOS or Linux mostly) so I have one available whenever I need it. It’s my go-to tool for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I have another Q where i don't have the d value..Struggling with the Python side of the questions

Comment: @Pkr96 post a new question on that then. You can solve the RSA without the $d$?

Comment: I have posted a new question! Can you? How so?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encrypt some text, then you take the message to a number $n < N$. the cypher text is then
$$ c = n^e \mod N $$
To recover the plaintext you calculate
$$ n = c^d \mod N $$
and then take this back to the plaintext

Comment: The OP's problem is not the maths, but the base conversion; see my answer