# Decrypting RSA when given N and E but not d

Tags: cryptography

The cipher text is O1v3nFbVCbuZLUeJDZO9L9 using the base-64 alphabet
N=15241604814814604814814604814814609737853
e=47
I know to work out d you factorize n which equals p and q then you get (p-1)*(q-1)
and finally e^-1 mod (p-1)*(q-1)
and then c^d mod N gives you the plaintext.
Struggling with the base-64 side of the Question!

Comment: It seems to me you're also struggling with the finding $d$ part of the question...

Comment: If it's multiple choice (your previous question was, I gather): encrypt all the possible answers and see which one matches the observed cipher text. That way you don't need $d$.

Comment: You're answer is one of the options! So it is correct

Comment: So you could have encrypted all the possible answers, as an easier way to solve the problem.

Comment: I think the latter way was the intended way of solving the question, BTW. No $d$ or factorisation needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code in [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2736389/4280) 
I get as the decimal number equivalent of the ciphertext: $3473726822818613085692498216956767492477$

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+15241604814814604814814604814814609737853) factorises your $N$ as

$$123457 \times 123456789123456789123456789123456829$$

This gives $$d=1297147349619189902810679264512807332559$$

and thus $$m= 42856312891220705415$$

which becomes `Llanymynech` (Welsh course?)

Remark:

If you know the answer is (again) a Welsh place name, take a list of them and encrypt each of them till you find a match for your ciphertext. There only a few 100 places to try at most, peanuts for computers nowadays. This already shows that the scheme is quite flawed in this form, even with larger $N$ (this one is tiny by realistic scenarios), as with such public key schemes random padding is added to elimate such attack scenarios.

Comment: How do i convert to Base 64 then?

Comment: @Pkr96 post the number, I'll convert it back

Comment: So the number is 3473726822818613085692498216956767492477^648573674809593865210809024512 mod 15241604814814604814814604814814609737853

Comment: @Pkr96 your numbers are wrong, see my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot..What am i doing wrong in the calculation?

Comment: @Pkr96 post your calculations. What tools do you have to work with large numbers?